# deep copy for C++ boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, deep-copy

I am trying to do deep copy for C++ boost::shared_ptr.

```
struct A{
   boost::shared_ptr<const Data> dataPtr;

   A(const A& aSource) {
      dataPtr.reset(new const Data);
      *dataPtr  = *(aSource.dataPtr);
};
```

But, i got error: 
     error: uninitialized const in 'new' of 'const struct A.

If I do not want to drop const, how to handle that ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: In this way, dataPtr will point to a non-const Data because of const_cast ? thanks !

Comment: The whole point of `shared_ptr` is to avoid deep copy.  If you want deep copy, you need a different pointer type.  (You also need a convention with regards to how to do deep copy.  A `Base*` may in fact point to a `Derived`, and it is the `Derived` which must be copied.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are trying to modify (in particular, to assign) a value through a `const` reference to it (because this is what dereferencing a `shared_ptr` to `const` gives you). Supposing `Data` has a copy constructor, you should rewrite your program this way:

```
struct A
{
    boost::shared_ptr<const Data> dataPtr;

    A(A const& aSource)
    {
        dataPtr.reset(new Data(*(aSource.dataPtr)));
    }
};
```